# SSMS: connecting to a network server database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

i need to connect to a database that is on a different server on the company network

i am using sql server 2005

i went to connect to server --> browse for more --> Network servers

but in the network servers list i am not seeing the server that i need.

how do i find the server that i need and connect to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can type in either the Server name or the IP address. The server may be configured to not broadcast its existance

Answer (score 1):

Type the server name into the Server text box if it's not appearing in the browse list.